# Formatting of the "from" attribute in cfmail behaves strangely

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

I don't know if this is a bug or just my failed understanding, but there seems to be a difference in the formatting of the `from` attribute in cfmail in the following two code examples:

**Example 1**

```
<cfmail to="customer@example.org"
  from="support@supplier.com (Customer Services)"
  subject="Order confirmation"
  type="html">
```

> `customer services <support@supplier.com>`

When sending mail using the above code, the name of the sender appears in lowercase.

**Example 2**

```
<cfmail to="customer@example.org"
  from="Customer Services <support@supplier.com>"
  subject="Order confirmation"
  type="html">
```

> `Customer Services <support@supplier.com>`

When sending mail using the above code, the name of the sender appears correctly:

Why does it format them differently? Is there any other setting I need to enable to stop the first code example from lowercasing everything?

Comment: This is a behaviour recently introduced. It was reported as a bug (https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4204050) and Adobe promised to fix it with another updater which the did not do: https://forums.adobe.com/message/10954938

Comment: There's another (older) thread in the Adobe forum: https://forums.adobe.com/message/10835468